# Glue table creation using Boto3

Tags: python, hive, boto3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We create a Glue table using boto3 method. The table is created and we are able to do msck repair from Hive or using Athena boto3.

The problem is the data is not populated to the Athena, in Athena only partitioned column is populated. where as in the Hive all the columns are populated.

Code for creating table using boto3

```
response = glue_client.create_table(
        DatabaseName='avro_database',
        TableInput={
            "Name": "avro_table_name",
            "Description": "Table created with boto3 API",
            "StorageDescriptor": {
                "Location": "s3://bucket_name/api/avro_folder",
                "InputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat",
                "OutputFormat": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat",
                "SerdeInfo": {
                    "SerializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe",
                    "Parameters": { 
                        "DeserializationLibrary": "org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe",
                    },
                },
            },
            "PartitionKeys": [
                {
                    "Name": "insert_yyyymmdd",
                    "Type": "string",
                }
            ],
            "TableType": "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
            "Parameters": {
                "avro.schema.url": "s3://bucket/schema/L1/api/schema_avro.avsc",
                'transient_lastDdlTime': '1635259605'
                
            }
        },
    )
```

after creating the table, we can also query the table definition in the Athena

DDL in athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE avro_table(
  `error_error_error_error_error_error_error` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `cannot_determine_schema` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `check` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `schema` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `url` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `and` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `literal` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `insert_yyyymmdd` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'DeserializationLibrary'='org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket_name/api/avro_folder'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.url"= "s3://bucket/schema/L1/api/schema_avro.avsc',
   'transient_lastDdlTime'= '1635259605')
```

when I query in Athena

`select * from "avro_database"."avro_table"`

Only partitioned column (insert_yyyymmdd ) is populated.

Comment: What is the outcome of your `msck repair table`? You need to have hive style partitions for this to work, i.e key=valuein your s3 location. Otherwise you will need to use `alter table add partition`

Comment: @Eman, msck repair is working fine, I have the partition in hive style only, i.e start_yyyyddmm=date in s3 location.

Answer (score 0):

Test case:

schema:

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "avro_table",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "error_error_error_error_error_error_error", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "cannot_determine_schema",  "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "check", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "schema", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "url", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "and", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "literal", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

python test code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("schema_avro.avsc", "rb").read())

writer = DataFileWriter(open("avro_table.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append({"error_error_error_error_error_error_error": "META confused", "cannot_determine_schema": "256", "check":"","schema": "meta verse","url":"http://aws.amazon.com", "and":"test", "literal": "chero"})
writer.append({"error_error_error_error_error_error_error": "Meta who", "cannot_determine_schema": "256", "check":"","schema": "meta verse","url":"http://aws.amazon.com", "and":"test", "literal": "chero"})
writer.append({"error_error_error_error_error_error_error": "META dead", "cannot_determine_schema": "256", "check":"","schema": "meta verse","url":"http://aws.amazon.com", "and":"test", "literal": "chero"})
writer.close()
```

Athena table or use a crawler:
Create table as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `avro_avro_data`(
  `error_error_error_error_error_error_error` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `cannot_determine_schema` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `check` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `schema` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `url` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `and` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `literal` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `insert_yyyymmdd` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'avro.schema.literal'='{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"avro_table\",\"namespace\":\"example.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"error_error_error_error_error_error_error\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"cannot_determine_schema\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"check\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"schema\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"url\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"and\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"literal\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]}]}') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://yourbucket/avro-data/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'avro.schema.literal'='{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"avro_table\",\"namespace\":\"example.avro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"error_error_error_error_error_error_error\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"cannot_determine_schema\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"check\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"schema\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"url\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"and\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]},{\"name\":\"literal\",\"type\":[\"string\",\"null\"]}]}', 
  'classification'='avro', 
  'compressionType'='none')
```

Your table created in Athena throws the following exception:
`table property 'avro.schema.url"= "s3://yourbucket/avro-schema/schema_avro.avsc' is not supported.`

Answer (score 0):

I think "/" is missing after avro_folder in  "Location": "s3://bucket_name/api/avro_folder"